# Why is my .fbx export broken?

Tags: armature, export, bezier-curves, .fbx

I created an animation of germinating process of a corn seed and I need to export the animation as glTF file and FBX file. i tried many method but most of them doesn't work with glTF or FBX export.

Then, I found a method that works with glTF export, and that is to make the bones to follow curves, just like the tutorial in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2aXjzxI6kXY, but it broken when exported to .FBX.

[image: The viewport view of the animation]

Where did I get wrong, is it the armature? because all my .FBX with armature exports are not working.

Here is the link to the file [image]